Mapbox Static API - How do I add multiple markers using nested GEOJSON
I have seen an example here where you can pass in multiple items in a geojson format.
However, this repeats the image URL for every marker. Given the space restrictions, I want to pass in nested GEOJSON, which the documentation says you can do. However I always get a 404.
Here is an example of my request:
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/streets-v11/static/geojson({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-url":"https%253A%252F%252Fwebsite.com%252Ffolder%252Ffolder2%252Ffolder3%252Ficon.png"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[2.2,41.4],[3.7,43.4],[12.3,45.4],[7.0,43.7],[15.3,37.5]]}}]})/8.1,42.28,4/800x600?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
I have tried encoding the whole geojson string as suggested in the documentation, but this doesn't help.
